# marionette, swap childview in collectionVeiw

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Would it be possible dynamically to change childView in collectionView

something like:

```
    //model
    var FooBar = Backbone.Model.extend({
      selected: false,
    });



    //collection view 
    var MyCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
          getChildView: function(item) {       
            if  (item.selected === true) {
              return FooView;
            }
            else {
              return BarView;
            }
          },

          // trigger from child view that should swap views
          // model.selected is now true  
         triggerFromChildView: function (childview, model) {
            //how to destroy childview and to re-create one for this model?
         } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically got it, but in order to make sure the new view gets created and rendered correctly, you need to re-render the entire collection view.

**1.)** You can listen to childView events and re-render the collectionView on childView model change.  There might be a more efficient way to do this but this will work:

```
var FooView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function(){
       this.trigger('item:model:change');
    });
  }
});

// get the collection view in place
var MyCollectionView = new CollectionView({
  getChildView: ...    
  //bind the function to the scope of the collection view
  onChildviewItemModelChange: _.bind(function() {
    this.render();
  },this)
});
```

**2.)** You can also try to removeChildView and addChild...but this involves more moving pieces that you need to manage. If you are working with a relatively small list, re-rendering the whole thing won't hurt performance.

- removeChildView: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/collection-view.js#L532
- addChild: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/collection-view.js#L429

**3.)** Another option is when the model changes, just `collection.reset(data)`, and then make sure you `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);` in your collectionView.

Comment: Thank you for idea. My first idea was to `copy` model `delete` (silent) model and then to `add` that model to collection again (that would trigger render  and with comparator new view will be placed on the same place where the old model was)